# How to call controller method in global.asax?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to call controller method in Global.asax. Code is given below.

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {      
            //here we can subscribe user to a role via Roles.AddUserToRole()
        }
    }
```

This event is in global.asax. I want to call controller method which return user permissions from database. How this is possible to call controller method here after that I will save user permissions in session and my controller constructor? Code is given below.

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{

    private readonly ISecurityService securityService;

    public AccountController(ISecurityService securityService)
    {
        this.securityService = securityService;
    }
}
```

Please guide me.

Comment: I would separate out the user permissions into a separate class and have both the controller and the global.asax call that class. I would avoid having any dependency between your global.asax and your controllers as you might end up with an infinite loop.

Comment: please can you give me any example @Rob Lang ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Resolve this issue by my self i call service method in global.asax by resolving dependency issue below is the solution of the above problem.

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            IUnityContainer container = GetUnityContainer();
            ISecurityService securityService = container.Resolve<SecurityService>();
            var list = securityService.GetUserRolesandPermissions("1");
        }
    }
```

Thank you every one.

Answer (score 2):

You could handle this using a custom [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). This allows you to place an attribute on the top of any controllers / methods which you require authentication to be successful in order to call. This lets you override [AuthorizeCore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.authorizecore%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) which you can then use to do any custom authorization you want to perform. You can also save any other information to session from this method.

For example:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        // do your own athorization stuff here
    }
}
```

Then you can decorate you controllers that require the use of this authorization either with your attribute:

```
[CustomAuthorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
}
```

Or using a base controller:

```
[CustomAuthorize]
public class BaseAuthController : Controller
{
}

public class AccountController : BaseAuthController
{
}
```